# On a series of lectures of Deligne on crystalline cohomology in characteristic $0$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, crystalline-cohomology, paper-request, crystals

In the introduction of Berthelot's book on crystalline cohomology [Ber74], one finds, on page 11, the following passage:

> *i) des travaux de P. Deligne ([14], non publiés) prouvant en particulier le théorème de comparaison entre cohomologie cristalline et cohomologie transcendante
> pour les schémas de type fini sur le corps des complexes, et amorçant une théorie des des "coefficients constructibles" pour la cohomologie cristalline en caractéristique $0$, de façon à tenir compte des points de vue nouveaux liés aux problèmes de constructibilité (notamment par l'emploi de pro-objects à la manière de l'Appendice de [30]), points de vue don't l'analogue en caractéristique $p>0$ reste à decouvrir;*

Are the contents of these exposés of Deligne [14] at the IHES available somewhere? (Say as later publications treating what was said in those lectures, papers mentioning it, written notes, etc.)

---

**Edit**: Eric Peterson mentioned that Grothendieck's Montreal Lectures on Dieudonné crystals ([[Original, FR]](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Eleila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/barsottitate.pdf), [[Eric's translation]](https://chromotopy.org/latex/misc/cristaux-eng.pdf)) also cite Deligne, with the precise reference being as follows:

> [6] Deligne, P. : Cohomologie cristalline en caractéristique 0, Seminaire IHES, à paraître aux Lecture Notes (?).

One also finds mentions of the seminar in the following references:

- [[Récoltes et Semailles, footnote 662]](https://www.quarante-deux.org/archives/klein/prefaces/Romans_1965-1969/Recoltes_et_semailles.pdf):

> Je me rappelle d’ailleurs que dans l’exposé que Deligne faisait de sa théorie, il évitait systématiquement le recours au langage
> cristallin, qui pourtant donnait à sa théorie une dimension plus profonde, en l’insérant dans un formalisme cohomologique
> topossique déjà existant. Egalement, je réalise que, tout comme Berthelot et mes autres élèves cohomologistes, il avait perdu le
> sens de l’unicité profonde entre la cohomologie cristalline en caractéristique p, et les phénomènes cristallins de caractéristique
> zéro (qui faisaient l’objet de son séminaire). Ce sont là des signes d’un propos délibéré d’ignorance d’une unité foncière, laquelle
> se trouve morcellée arbitrairement et par là, détruire. Ce propos délibéré est dans la nature d’un "blocage", par intervention de
> forces de nature égotique, étrangères à la pulsion de connaissance. Pour une illustration de ce blocage chez un autre de mes
> élèves cohomologistes, que j’ai pourtant connu doué d’une fine intuition, voir la sous-note n ◦ 91 2 à la note "Les cohéritiers... ".

- [Sur les coefficients de de Rham–Grothendieck des varietes algebriques](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0091144) (there's a good deal of information about what's treated in Deligne there):

> [D$_2$] —, Cristaux discontinus, Notes manuscrites non publiées qui datent du début des annees 70 (19 pages).

- [Constructible isocrystals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.07046):

> In a handwritten note [10] called “Cristaux discontinus”, Pierre Deligne gave an algebraic interpretation of the right hand side of this equivalence. More precisely, he introduces the notion of constructible pro-coherent crystal and proves an equivalence
> $$\mathrm{Cons}_{\mathrm{reg},\text{pro-coh}}(X/\mathbb{C})\simeq\mathrm{Cons}(X^\mathrm{an})$$
> between the categories of regular constructible pro-cohererent crystals and constructible $\mathbb{C}_{X^\mathrm{an}}$-modules.
>
> [10] Pierre Deligne. Cristaux discontinus. note.

- [Logarithmic De Rham, Infinitesimal and Betti Cohomologies](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0407402):

> Deligne, P., Cristaux Discontinus, unpublished notes (1970).

- [Pierre Deligne: A Poet of Arithmetic Geometry](https://www.abelprize.no/binfil/download.php?tid=74252) (A full page of information there!)

> The case of characteristic zero retained less attention. In his seminar at the IHÉS in 1970 [62] Deligne generalized both the Riemann–Hilbert correspondence (16) and the comparison isomorphism (21) to certain crystals onpossibly singular schemes over $\mathbb{C}$
>
> 62. P. Deligne. Cristaux discontinus  Handwritten notes, 1970, unpublished.

- [Constructible $\nabla$-Modules on Curves](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3279):

> In between, we have the category of constructible pro-crystals (unpublished note of Deligne ([13])
>
> [16] Pierre Deligne. Cristaux discontinus. Unpublished manuscript.

- [Towards an overconvergent Deligne–Kashiwara correspondence](http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/lauder/workshop/talks/LeStum-Slides.pdf); see slide 12.

---

> [14] P. Deligne, Cristaux en caractéristique zéro, exposés a l'IHES, Mars 1970 (non rédigés).

> [Ber74] Pierre Berthelot. [Cohomologie Cristalline des Schémas de Caractéristique $p > 0$](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540068525). Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 407. Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York, 1974, p. 604

Comment: For what it's worth, [Deligne's IAS page](http://publications.ias.edu/deligne/section/345) doesn't list it.

Comment: neither does a search on Numdam turn up anything

Comment: Maybe it's worth contacting Deligne?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I'm thinking about contacting him too, but I'll wait a bit more to see if someone here on MO knows a bit more about the notes. (I'm specially curious about Grothendieck referring to them as `à paraître aux Lecture Notes (?)` with them being mentioned elsewhere as 19 handwritten pages only... What else was planned to be developed there but ultimately wasn't? Or maybe Deligne just has really small handwriting :P)

Comment: Did you succeed?

Comment: @Yai0Phah I actually had forgotten to send the email, which was sitting there as a draft! I think I got too intimidated to ultimately send it at the time, but I sent it now. Thanks for the ping!

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: @Z.M Hi! From what I remember Deligne didn't reply, but I later asked Bernard Le Stum, who generously shared a copy with me =)

Comment: @Emily Can you share it here? It would be useful to have it available for future searchers.

Comment: @Compacto Hi! I'm not sure if it's okay for me to share it here without Le Stum's authorization unfortunately =/, I'd recommend for the moment asking him for a copy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After asking Mr Le Stum for the scan which Emily talked about in the comments to the original post, he kindly sent it to me, with permission to share it publicly. It is, according to him, a "bad copy".

Here it is:

[Deligne, P. "Cristaux Discontinus". Handwritten notes. 1970](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGXB9JcikGu3V60gHS2qAg5eu65Mja0B/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Yaayy! I hadn't thought about asking Le Stum if it would be okay to share the copy publicly, but now it is finally available online. Thank you for having thought this and asking him!

Comment: @Emily With pleasure.